# Como ordenar e desordenar um datatable em JSF clicando na coluna?

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Bom galera, eu tenho uma aplicação em JSF, gostaria de saber como faço para ordenar e desordenar datatable ao clicar na coluna, nesse tabela existe 6 colunas e 3 delas gostaria que eu ao clicar ela ordenasse de acordo com a coluna clicada?

*consulta por demanda

Comment: Provavelmente você vai querer usar collection.sort() no seu bean. Mas você pode fazer isso de várias maneiras, segue abaixo alguns exemplos inclusive com código de exemplo pra download. Este exemplo aqui deve se enquadrar melhor no seu caso de consulta por demanda
http://uaihebert.com/paginacao-de-datatable-lazy-com-jsf-primefaces/ http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-sorting-example/ http://www.guj.com.br/java/42554-jsf--ordenacao-de-datatable

Comment: o que exatamente seria `desordenar`? você quer deixar suas linhas aleatórias? qual a dificuldade você está tendo? poderia mostrar a parte relevante do seu código?

Comment: ORDENAR: crescente: 123456 decrescente: 654321
DESORDENA: 643521

Comment: A parte de desordenar fica meio complicadinho usando o "sortBy" do "primefaces". Terias de implementar o próprio métodos de ordenação e gerar, dentre os possíveis valores, linhas aleatórias.

Answer (score 4):

Se estiver usando ou puder usar o Primefaces, basta incluir a propriedade "sortBy" em seu column

```
<p:dataTable value="#{testeMB.objetos}" var="o">
  <p:column headerText="Nome" sortBy="#{o.nome}">
    #{o.nome}
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Noto apenas que o "objetos" precisa ser um atributo de uma classe(incluindo a Managed ou Named) e não apenas um método que retorna a lista de objetos.